# Proving that $f_n(x)=\sin^{n}(x)$ is uniformly convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Consider $$f_n\left(x\right)\:=\:\sin ^n\left(x\right)$$
How to prove that this sequence is uniformly convergent in $\left[0,b\right]\: \text{for}\:\frac{\pi }{2}>b>0$?

Comment: Would $|f_n(x)|\leqslant\beta^n$ for every $x$ in $[0,b]$, with $\beta=\sin b\lt1$, do the job?

Answer (score 2):

The function $x\mapsto \sin x$ is increasing on the interval $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$ so
$$\left|\sin^n(x)\right|\le \sin ^nb\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0,\quad\forall x\in[0,b]$$
so the sequence is uniformly convergent on $[0,b]$.

Comment: why we need to use ∑nsinnb ?

Comment: i see the function sinx is increasin on the interval, and understand the equation you made, but the last sentence i don't understand

Comment: Sorry I thought you ask for the series and not the sequence. I'll edit.

Comment: Sweet and succinct!

Answer (score 0):

For all $x\in[0,b]$,
$$
|f_n(x)|\le\sin^n(b)
$$
and since $0\le\sin(b)\lt1$, we have that $f_n(x)\to0$ uniformly; that is, given an $\epsilon\gt0$, we can find an $N$ so that for $n\ge N$, $|f_n(x)|\le\epsilon$ independent of $x\in[0,b]$. The following will do

$$N=\left\lceil\frac{\log(\epsilon)}{\log(\sin(b))}\right\rceil$$

Comment: how can you find this N?

Comment: @user2637293: If $\beta=\sin(b)$ and $k=\log_\beta(\varepsilon)$ we have $f_k(x)\leq\beta^k=\varepsilon$. Then just choose $N$ as any integer greater than $k$.

Comment: @user2637293: I have added an explicit formula for $N$.